# Comparing props in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Facebook documentation suggests we should compare props before making network requests in `componentDidUpdate()` -- see following link: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html.

I have a component that is used in multiple modules of my app and this component needs to make an API request to get its data. So I want to make sure I handle the comparison the right way because in the past I've run into issues with shallow compares. It's important to note that I need to make an API request upon initial load and I'm not sure how props change -- or not -- in initial load.

What's the right way to compare props in `componentDidUpdate()` method?

I'm also curious if I should always use `componentDidUpdate()` for API calls?

Comment: Use `componentDidMount` to fire API call if its on first load only

Comment: Also, consider using `shouldComponentUpdate` to do comparisons to see if your component should update at all.  If you need a deep comparison on small object graphs you can always use `JSON.stringify(myProp)` and compare the output.